# HashMap : Adding values with common keys and printing them out

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have file which has String in the form `key/value` pair like people and count, example would be

```
"Reggy, 15"
"Jenny, 20"
"Reggy, 4"
"Jenny, 5"
```

and in the output I should have summed up all count values based on key so for our example output would be

"Reggy, 19"
"Jenny, 25"

Here is my approach:

1. Read each line and for each line get key and count using scanner and having `,` as delimiter
2. Now see if key is already present before if then just add currentValues to previousValues if not then take currentValue as value of HashMap.

Sample Implementation:

```
public static void main(final String[] argv) {
    final File file = new File("C:\\Users\\rachel\\Desktop\\keyCount.txt");

    try {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            if (scanner.hasNext(".*,")) {
                String key;
                final String value;

                key = scanner.next(".*,").trim();

                if (!(scanner.hasNext())) {
                    // pick a better exception to throw
                    throw new Error("Missing value for key: " + key);
                }

                key = key.substring(0, key.length() - 1);
                value = scanner.next();

                System.out.println("key = " + key + " value = " + value);
            }
        }
    } catch (final FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Part I am not clear about is how to divide key/value pair while reading them in and creating HashMap based on that.

Also is the approach am suggestion an optimal one or is there a way to enhance the performance more.

Comment: did you try `java.util.HashMap#containsKey(),put(),get()` ?

Comment: It's "pseudocode" :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this is almost certainly a learning exercise, I'll stay away from writing code, letting you have all the fun.

Create a `HashMap<String,Integer>`. Every time that you see a key/value pair, check if the hash map has a value for the key (use 'containsKey(key)'). If it does, get that old value using `get(key)`, add the new value, and store the result back using `put(key, newValue)`. If the key is not there yet, add a new one - again, using `put`. Don't forget to make an `int` out if the `String value` (use `Integer.valueOf(value)` for that).

As far as optimizing goes, any optimization at this point would be premature: it does not even work! However, it's hard to get much faster than a single loop that you have, which is also rather straightforward.

Comment: I am aware about that part of implementation but issue am having is while reading key/value pair data in.

Comment: @Rachel This should be really straightforward if you use `Scanner` to read lines, and then use `split` Take a look at [this sample on ideone](http://ideone.com/3zeQ3A) for a demo.

Answer (score 2):

For reading in, personally, I'd use:

`Scanner.nextLine()`, `String.split(",")`, and `Integer.valueOf(value)`

Comment: Should be split(",") since it expects a String.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String, Long>();

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        if (scanner.hasNext(".*,")) {
            ....
            if(map.containsKey(key))
                map.put(key, map.get(key) + Long.valueOf(value));
            else
                map.put(key, Long.valueOf(value));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why Long, certainly the numbers look like age. shouldn't be worried about exceeding Integer's values

Comment: look like age? Then these two Reggie and Jenny are not the same person :-) which is a completely different case. Besides `looks like` is not a good argument.

Comment: That's true, however, should be picked judiciously.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way I can think about splitting the values:

```
    BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    Map<String, Integer> mapping = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    String currentLine;
    while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] pair  = currentLine.split(",");

         if(pair.length != 2){ //could be less strict
            throw new DataFormatException();
         }

         key = pair[0];
         value = Integer.parseInt(pair[1]);
         if(map.contains(key)){
             value +=  map.get(key);
         }
         map.put(key,value);
    }
```

It is most likely not the most efficient way in terms of performance, but is pretty straightforward. `Scanner` is usually used for parsing, but the parsing here doesn't look as complex, is just a split of strings.

Answer (score 0):

**Kind of late but clean solution with time complexity of O(n). This solution bypasses sort of arrays**

```
 public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Anagram
            String str1 = "School master";
            String str2 = "The classroom";


            char strChar1[] = str1.replaceAll("[\\s]", "").toLowerCase().toCharArray();
            char strChar2[] = str2.replaceAll("[\\s]", "").toLowerCase().toCharArray();

            HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

            for (char c : strChar1) {
                if(map.containsKey(c)){
                    int value=map.get(c)+1;
                    map.put(c, value);
                 }else{
                     map.put(c, 1);
                 }

            }

            for (char c : strChar2) {
                if(map.containsKey(c)){
                    int value=map.get(c)-1;
                    map.put(c, value);
                 }else{
                     map.put(c, 1); 
                 }
            }

            for (char c : map.keySet()) {
                if (map.get(c) != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Not anagram");
                }
            }
                    System.out.println("Is anagram");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Map<String, Integer> mergeMaps(@NonNull final Map<String, Integer> mapOne,
                                          @NonNull final Map<String, Integer> mapTwo) {
        return Stream.of(mapOne.entrySet(), mapTwo.entrySet())
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Integer::sum));
    }
```